# Access limit a node after a certain period of time

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'd like to be able to have nodes of a certain type "access denid" after every day
if user role is `PRO` only 2 time can edit the node and everytime user role is `ADVANCE` can edit node 10 time in every day

What's the best way to achieve this result?

```
function MY_MODULE_check_node_access($op, $node){
  global $user;
  // Note $op and $node are passed in default node_menu access arguments
  // Allow bypass by users with administer nodes permission
  if (($op == 'update') && (!user_access('administer nodes'))) {
  // Allow edit access to node author if within time limit
  if ($user->uid == $node->uid) {
  $limit = variable_get('node_edit_limit', (15 * 60));
  if ((REQUEST_TIME - $node->created) > $limit) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Edit time limit exceeded'));
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
}     
 // Fallback to regular node_access checks
  return node_access($op, $node);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the hook is hook_node_access
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x
so your function should be named MY_MODULE_node_access($op, $node)

Also you dont have to implement hook_menu_alter
Drupal menu items are cached so there is no purpose trying to evaluate them on every request.
However just implementing hook_node_access should be enough
last dont return TRUE and FALSE but NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE and NODE_ACCESS_DENY instead. Check the documentation of hook_node_access on the link above

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend !

Comment: Can i set limit ? like 2 time in every day ?